# R panel dataset find all time-varying variables

Tags: r

Consider a dataset of the form:

```
person year A  B  C
1      2000 1 0.5 cat
1      2001 1 0.7 NA
1      2002 1 0.5 dog
2      2000 3 0.3 dog
2      2001 3 0.4 dog
2      2002 3 0.9 dog
```

This data set has a panel structure: people are followed over time. How could I find in R which variables are time-variant and which are time-invariant without considering the NA? Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please make this a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the `dplyr` version:

```
# load the package
library(dplyr)

# create the sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
    person = c("A", "B", "A", "B")
    , year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001)
    , A = c("k", "k", "k", "k")
    , B = c("m", "l", "m", "m")
    , C = c("m", NA, "m", "m")
)

# a function that gives `TRUE` if all values in a vector are the same
allTheSame <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1

# and now
df %>% # we take the dataframe
    group_by(person) %>% # group it by person
    summarise_all(allTheSame) # and apply our function to all columns
```